# How can one run a JS script on current ASP.Net aspx page from another thread?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am running a thread that is checking for whether new data is available. When new data is available I would like to simply run a JS alert, i.e `alert("new data")` to display a popup message on the currently accessed page. 

I have attempted the following (running this code in the 2nd thread):

```
//...
if(dataIsAvailable)
{
  //...
  HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<script>alert('new data')</script>");
}
//...
```

However I get an exception for the following reason:

> `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.**get** returned null.`

How can one run a JS script on the current page from outside that page in another thread?

Thank you

Comment: You are aware of the separation of client and server (and the code they execute)? You might want to have a look at SignalR.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible.

What you try to do is to send some message to page, but **the connection to the page is not exist any more on this thread** - and so the `System.Web.HttpContext.Current` is null

Imaging that... client ask for a page, and server send this page, client renders it and close the connection, nothing more to get, nothing more to render. Now on the server side a thread is run and you have some results... but there is no output any more to send them.

Maybe you can find solution with ajax calls - or just remove the thread and wait to finish it.